# TeXStudio epstopdf error

Tags: texstudio, epstopdf

I get peculiar errors when creating pdf from LateX code:

Extra \endcsname. \SetupKeyvalOptions{family=ETE,prefix=ETE@}

No pdf is created.
When I click the error, I land up epstopdf-base.sty file on a oine stating

\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=ETE,prefix=ETE@}

What the heck is going on here - and what should I do to prevent this error?

Edit: I stripped the code to the bare minimum, still getting the error. Apparently the combination of packages tikz and tikz-euclide causes the error (?).
I now get an extra error on koptions.sty, see below.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,thmtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes, arrows, calc, intersections, through, backgrounds}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
        
\end{document}

line 433: Extra \endcsname. }
line 433: Extra \endcsname. }
line 433: Extra \endcsname. }
line 433: Extra \endcsname. }
line 186: Extra \endcsname. \SetupKeyvalOptions{family=ETE,prefix=ETE@}
line 186: Extra \endcsname. \SetupKeyvalOptions{family=ETE,prefix=ETE@}
line 186: Extra \endcsname. \SetupKeyvalOptions{family=ETE,prefix=ETE@}
line 186: Extra \endcsname. \SetupKeyvalOptions{family=ETE,prefix=ETE@}
```

Comment: you have not given any clues that would allow anyone to reproduce or debug this. Please show a small complete document , and show the complete error message that you get  from the log file. texstudio is just the editor you use to write the file, it is unrelated to the error, and it is rare to need to explicitly load `epstopdf` package, what is your use case here?

Comment: I get no error with this document with pdflatex in texlive2020

Comment: No error here with TeXLive 2019. No output too, but that's normal for an empty document. Clean up auxiliary files and try again.